# Convert DateTime to ISO 8601 DateTime Format with timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, iso8601

How do I convert my time from 2010-12-30 23:21:46 to ISO 8601 date format?

I tried `$datetime->format(DateTime::ATOM)` and `date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2010-12-30 23:21:46'))` which converts into ISO8601 format like `2016-12-31T09:47:50+0000`. But what i need is `2018-02-19T05:43:59.753000Z` format. How can i achieve using PHP??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to output format in Zulu/UTC/GMT timezone, then you must first convert timezone, since I do not know in which timezone is your current setup.

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2010-12-30 23:21:46');
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/982792)**</kbd>

---

And ISO-8601 is a standard that has many variations of format:

- `2018-04-03`
- `2018-04-03T05:20:03+00:00`
- `2018-04-03T05:20:03Z`
- `20180403T052003Z`
- `2018-W14`
- `2018-W14-2`
- ...

This are all valid ISO-8601 formats. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).